# How to make computed field inside One2many tree view visible before parent form is saved

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

What i have so farm is form with One2many field presented as tree view:

```
<field name="o2m_field" options='{"always_reload": True}' nolabel="1" widget="one2many_list" mode="tree,kanban" context="{'form_view_ref': 'my_customer_form'}">
                                <tree string="Route Location">
                                    <field name="name"/>
                                    <!-- name consists of address city and code -->
                                    <field name="address" invisible="1"/>
                                    <field name="city" invisible="1"/>
                                    <field name="code" invisible="1"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
```

As I click to add item new form is being opened. As I fill data and click "Save&close" everything is shown inside my o2many tree expect for name. Name becomes visible only as I click save on parent form.

Python code for computing field:

```
name = fields.Char(readonly=True, compute='name_line', store=True)


@api.one
@api.depends('name', 'address', 'city', 'code')
def name_line(self):
    cust_name = ''
    if self.address:
        cust_name += self.address + '/'

    if self.load_city:
        cust_name += self.load_city + '/'

    if self.load_postcode:
        cust_name += self.load_postcode + '/'

    if len(cust_name) > 0:
        if cust_name[-1] == '/':
            cust_name = cust_name[:-1]

    if self.name != cust_name:
        self.name = cust_name
```

I tried making always_reload, stored = false and several other solutions that I cant even remember. working on this for several hours (days)

Thanks for your time considering my question, have a great day!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding `on_change` event for `address, city & postalcode` fields, which will compute the `name` field and will show it you even before you save the form data.